# Se pude incluir codigo php dentro de un archivo Javascript externo?

Tags: javascript, php

Buen dia tengo la duda de si se puede ejecutar codigo php dentro de un archivo Js externo, quiero capturar el evento de clic de un botón de eliminar y dependiendo del tipo de usuario por medio de $_SESSION, mostrarle una alerta de confirmación diferente, ya que lo requiero para una funcionalidad.. Dejo mi codigo javascript abajo

```
$(".eliminar").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      var id = $(this).attr('href');

      //aqui quiero correr mi codigo php que seria por medio de SESSION
      
      Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Está seguro de realizar esta acción?',
        text: "No será posible deshacer el cambio",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si , deseo eliminar!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar!'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            enviaDatos(id);
       
        }

      })
    });
```

Comment: a qué te refieres con JS externo? no puedes llamar una función de ese JS y pasarle por parámetro lo que tienes en php?

Comment: tendrías que tener un archivo .php  el cual contenga las instrucciones JS para poder obtener el valor de tus variables y que el resultante sea la salida que necesites. Esa salida la puedes procesar mediante un include y tener "externo" tu archivo

Comment: @L.Ronquillo lo tengo en un js aparte que se llama confirmar.js y lo incluyo en el html a traves de link, y cuando hace clic al boton eliminar, llama la funcion que me muestra esta alerta y si confirmo hago un ajax para mandar el id del registro que quiero eliminar , pero requiero validar el tipo de usuario para mostrar una alerta de confirmacion diferente...

Comment: Si se puede, pero no sería recomendable.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Como podria mostrar una alerta distinca segun el tipo de usuario?

Comment: Dame contexto para poder entenderte.

Answer (score 1):

No es posible lo que dices pero puedes hacer algo como esto

```php
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <button id="delete-message" data-user-type="<?php echo $_SESSION['userType']; ?>">
      eliminar
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y desde el javascript leer el tipo de usuario así:

```js
  var el = document.querySelector('#delete-message')
  var type = el.dataset.userType

  $(".eliminar").click(function(event) {
    Swal.fire({
      title: '¿Está seguro de realizar esta acción?',
      text: type == 'tipo 1' ? 'Un mensaje' : type == 'tipo 2' ? 'Otro mensaje' : 'Mensaje en caso de fallar las anteriores condiciones',
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Si , deseo eliminar!',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar!'
    })
  }
```

Es un ejemplo algo básico pero explica la lógica de lo que tienes que hacer, solo imprime en un atributo `data` el tipo de usuario y cambia el contenido de la alerta dependiendo de el.

También puedes imprimir directamente el mensaje según el usuario, en el atributo `data`, con **PHP**

Este atributo data no necesariamente tiene que ir en el botón de la alerta

Answer (score 0):

Desde PHP, antes de incluir el script externo puedes crear una variable con el tipo de usuario, por ejemplo:

```
<script>
let tipoUsuario = '<?php echo $_SESSION['tipo_usuario']; ?>';
</script>
<!-- Abajo puedes incluir tu script externo -->
<script src="ruta/script.js"></script>
```

Luego, en tu script externo analizas si existe la variable y su valor:

```
$(".eliminar").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      let id = $(this).attr('href');

      // Analizas si la variable está definida y su valor es el adecuado
      if(typeof tipoUsuario != 'undefined' && tipoUsuario == 'Valor deseado') {
          // Muestras la otra confirmación y sales de la función
          return;
      }
      // La variable no está definida o el valor no corresponde
      // Muestras la confirmación por defecto
      Swal.fire({
        title: '¿Está seguro de realizar esta acción?',
        text: "No será posible deshacer el cambio",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si , deseo eliminar!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar!'
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            enviaDatos(id);
       
        }
      })
});
```